# Removing key from Map in case of Atomic Values

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency, atomic, key-value

I want to remove keys from map in case if the value for the key is **zero(0)** i am able to achieve it using 
`map.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton(0l));`
.

It was working nice till i was using **`Map<String,Long>`** but now we have changed the implementation to **`Map<String,AtomicLong>`** now it dosen't remove the keys whose values are zero since i am using an Atomic variable as value.

 Small code snippet on which i tried ::

```
    Map<String, AtomicLong> atomicMap = new HashMap<String,AtomicLong>();
    atomicMap.put("Ron", new AtomicLong(0l));
    atomicMap.put("David", new AtomicLong(0l));
    atomicMap.put("Fredrick", new AtomicLong(0l));
    atomicMap.put("Gema", new AtomicLong(1l));
    atomicMap.put("Andrew", new AtomicLong(1l));    

    atomicMap.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton(new AtomicLong(0l)));

    System.out.println(atomicMap.toString());
```

which outputs as 
`{Ron=0, Fredrick=0, Gema=1, Andrew=1, David=0}`

as you can see the keys which have values 0 are not being removed. Can anyone suggest a solution over this , it will be of great help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two instances of `AtomicLong` are never equal. If you look at `AtomicLong` you can see that it never overrides the `equal()` method. See [Why are two AtomicIntegers never equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567502/why-are-two-atomicintegers-never-equal)

You can overcome this with your own custom `AtomicLong` implementation, which implements `equals()` and make your strategy to remove the elements work.

```
public class MyAtomicLongExample {

    static class MyAtomicLong extends AtomicLong {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8694980851332228839L;

        public MyAtomicLong(long initialValue) {
            super(initialValue);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return obj instanceof MyAtomicLong && ((MyAtomicLong) obj).get() == get();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, MyAtomicLong> atomicMap = new HashMap<>();
        atomicMap.put("Ron", new MyAtomicLong(0l));
        atomicMap.put("David", new MyAtomicLong(0l));
        atomicMap.put("Fredrick", new MyAtomicLong(0l));
        atomicMap.put("Gema", new MyAtomicLong(1l));
        atomicMap.put("Andrew", new MyAtomicLong(1l));    

        atomicMap.values().removeAll(Collections.singleton(new MyAtomicLong(0l)));

        System.out.println(atomicMap);
    }

}
```

This will print `{Gema=1, Andrew=1}`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java8, there is a `removeIf` method that you could use.

```
atomicMap.values().removeIf(x -> x.get() == 0L);
// Prints {Gema=1, Andrew=1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase if you want to compute then decide to remove when value is zero.

```
if (atomicMap.compute("Andrew", (k, v) ->  v.decrementAndGet()) == 0) {

      atomicMap.remove("Andrew");
}
```